# How do I get the source of a very specific version of spring from github?

Tags: spring, github

I'm trying to debug a problem and need the matching source for spring-context 5.0.5.  I got 5.0.x from the GitHub (or elsewhere), but when I try to step through the instruction pointer clearly isn't matching up.  How can I get 5.0.5 specifically?

Comment: you could download the maven "sources" artifact (when available)...

Comment: ..and in github: you can see it/switch to it under : tags! https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/v5.0.5.RELEASE/spring-context ;)

Comment: Maven Central contains source code for Spring artifacts. Spring 5.0.5 can be found [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-context/5.0.5.RELEASE/).

Comment: Which IDE are you using to debug? Good ones will allow you to decompile the jars used in your code and offer to download sources as well.

Comment: @xerx593 - Perfect!  I just didn't see that tags tab that lets you select it.